# Spring Boot Controller Test throws No qualifying bean of type Service Name

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have two controller test class named UserControllerTest and AuthenticationControllerTest through JUnit in Spring Boot.

Here is the

```
@WebMvcTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles(value = "dev")
public abstract class UserControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;


    @Test
    void test1() throws Exception {

    }
}
```

Here is the

```
@WebMvcTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles(value = "dev")
public abstract class AuthenticationControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private AuthService authService;


    @Test
    void test1() throws Exception {

    }
}
```

When I run test of **AuthenticationControllerTest**, I get this issue shown below

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.user.service.UserService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

When I run test of **UserControllerTest**, I get this issue shown below

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.user.service.AuthService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

How can I fix this inconsistent issue in Spring Boot Integration Tests for both controller.
I already defined `@Service` annotation in both service.

Answer (score 1):

According to the @WebMvcTest [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html) @Service beans will not be loaded:

> Annotation that can be used for a Spring MVC test that focuses only on Spring MVC components.
> Using this annotation will disable full auto-configuration and instead apply only configuration relevant to MVC tests (i.e. @Controller, @ControllerAdvice, @JsonComponent, Converter/GenericConverter, Filter, WebMvcConfigurer and HandlerMethodArgumentResolver beans but not @Component, @Service or @Repository beans).

> If you are looking to load your full application configuration and use MockMVC, you should consider @SpringBootTest combined with @AutoConfigureMockMvc rather than this annotation.

Comment: How can I revise the test class? Can you help me?

Comment: Change WebMvcTest annotation to SpringBootTest combined with AutoConfigureMockMvc

Answer (score 0):

In Spring MVC tests, all controllers are included in the application context, if not specified, and therefore all their dependencies should also be available. That's why the `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` is thrown for a bean from another `RestController`.

To specify controllers to test, set the `value` or the `controllers` parameter of [`@WebMvcTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html), for example:

```java
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
...
public abstract class UserControllerTest {
    ...
}
```

`@WebMvcTest` is usually used for writing unit tests for controllers. If you want to write integration tests for multiple layers of your application you should consider `@SpringBootTest` combined with `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` to load the full application context where, in general, mocks should not be used.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add **@SpringBootTest** annotation to load the beans from application context.

Your test class should look like this.

```
@WebMvcTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles(value = "dev")
@SpringBootTest
public class AuthenticationControllerTest {
    @MockBean private AuthService authService;
    @Autowired private UserService userService;
.....
}
```

Comment: This is not a good solution, since `@SpringBootTest` starts a full application context.

Comment: Generally, there is nothing bad in loading the full context. In some cases it can be even better for performance, for example when you have many test classes, because they will use the same context from the cache. Still in this answer WebMvcTest annotation is not needed, we can substitute it to AutoConfigureMockMvc

Comment: @TanbirulHashan I don't use UserService in  AuthenticationControllerTest.